# How to get alert text in jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, alert, response.write

I called 'alert' box from C#

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Click Checkbox'); </script>");
```

and I want to get this **text** from 'alert' box in jQuery. Text what I want is 'Click Checkbox'.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather set a variable from code behind and access the value. contents of alert do not have the scope of accessing it.

```
Response.Write("<script>var alerttext='Click Checkbox'; alert('Click Checkbox'); </script>");
```

Comment: !!! oh it's so easy. Thank you. And I got another curious... If I write multiple code in Response.Wirte, can I write jQuery code in this code?

Comment: absolutely. but make sure the jquery script is going to get loaded first.